# How we can implement a blur effect like iOS 14 AppLibrary? ( The blur effect behind the SearchBar )

Tags: ios, swiftui, blur

I want to make a blurry header like the iOS 14 AppLibrary.

Check this image:

[image: iOS 14 app library blur header]

I have something like this code:

```
  GeometryReader { proxy in
    ZStack(alignment: .leading){
      ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false, content: {
        Spacer()
         .frame(height: 48, alignment: .center)
         .padding(.horizontal, 24)
          .padding(.top, proxy.safeAreaInsets.top)
          .hidden()

        ...

      }).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
      
      //Need that beautiful blurry header here!          

      VStack(alignment: .center, content: {
        SearchBar()
         .frame(height: 48, alignment: .center)
         .padding(.horizontal, 24)
        
        Spacer()
      })
    }.frame(width: proxy.size.width)
  }
```

I'm not sure if there is something between the searchBar and ScrollView or not.

Do you have any ideas about the implementation?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for an `UIVisualEffectView`. This isn't available in pure SwiftUI, but you can port it over from UIKit using `UIViewRepresentable`. Check out this [article](https://medium.com/@edwurtle/blur-effect-inside-swiftui-a2e12e61e750).

Comment: I've tested UIVisualEffectView before but it has not the same effect like the image I've attached